# How to insert multiple rows to a pandas DF with a missing value?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[0,1,3,5,6], "B":['B0','B1','B3','B5','B6'], "C":['C0','C1','C3','C5','C6']})
```

I’m trying to insert 10 empty rows at the position where the number is missed from the continuous sequence of column A. For the 10 rows, values of column A, B and C's are the missed number, Nan, and Nan, respectively. Like this:

```
A   B   C
0   B0  C0
1   B1  C1
2   NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN
3   B3  C3
4   NaN NaN
4   NaN NaN
4   NaN NaN
4   NaN NaN
4   NaN NaN
4   NaN NaN
4   NaN NaN
4   NaN NaN
4   NaN NaN
4   NaN NaN
5   B5  C5
6   B6  C6
```

I've played with index, but this adds only 1 row:

```
df1 = df.merge(how='right', on='A', right = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.arange(df.iloc[0]['A'],
                                                                        df.iloc[-1]['A']+1)})).reset_index().drop(['index'], axis=1)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to [`repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) the indices where the values [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) is above 1 and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
N = 10
out = (pd.concat([df, df[['A']].loc[df.index.repeat(df['A'].diff(-1).lt(-1).mul(N-1))]])
         .sort_index(kind='stable')
      )
```

Output:

```
   A    B    C
0  0   B0   C0
1  1   B1   C1
1  1  NaN  NaN
1  1  NaN  NaN
1  1  NaN  NaN
1  1  NaN  NaN
1  1  NaN  NaN
1  1  NaN  NaN
1  1  NaN  NaN
1  1  NaN  NaN
1  1  NaN  NaN
2  3   B3   C3
2  3  NaN  NaN
2  3  NaN  NaN
2  3  NaN  NaN
2  3  NaN  NaN
2  3  NaN  NaN
2  3  NaN  NaN
2  3  NaN  NaN
2  3  NaN  NaN
2  3  NaN  NaN
3  5   B5   C5
4  6   B6   C6
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach could be as follows:

- First, use [`df.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to make column `A` the index.
- Next, use [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) for a range that runs from `0` through to the max of `A` (i.e. `6`).
- Now, apply [`df.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) based on [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html). We use a loop to feed a `1` to the `repeats` parameter for all the values that exist in `A`, for all the ones that are missing, we use `10`.
- Finally, chain [`df.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).

```
df.set_index('A', inplace=True)
rng = range(df.index.max()+1)
df = df.reindex(np.repeat(rng,[1 if i in df.index else 10 for i in rng]))\
    .reset_index(drop=False)

print(df)

    A    B    C
0   0   B0   C0
1   1   B1   C1
2   2  NaN  NaN
3   2  NaN  NaN
4   2  NaN  NaN
5   2  NaN  NaN
6   2  NaN  NaN
7   2  NaN  NaN
8   2  NaN  NaN
9   2  NaN  NaN
10  2  NaN  NaN
11  2  NaN  NaN
12  3   B3   C3
13  4  NaN  NaN
14  4  NaN  NaN
15  4  NaN  NaN
16  4  NaN  NaN
17  4  NaN  NaN
18  4  NaN  NaN
19  4  NaN  NaN
20  4  NaN  NaN
21  4  NaN  NaN
22  4  NaN  NaN
23  5   B5   C5
24  6   B6   C6
```